# Android telephone with a screen that works inside the rain/water spray just as well as in dry region

Tags: screen

Well I keep having to fight with all telephones I buy. often wishing back to the time when you could just call instead of having to type on a touch pad.

Not because I don't like it, but because the smart screens seem to live their own lives when they get wet/droplets fall on them.

In my work and generally whereever I am it's more often than not wet and I need to be able to communicate with people in those weathers. I could of course wipe the screen, but within seconds the screen is doing its own thing already. (Currently owning a pixel 3). On top of that even in dry weather the screen seems to have a lot of "ghost" clicks when I touch it, that or it doesn't recognize my touches at all...

Is there a way I can make the screen less random and working better in rain?

I've tried several models, pixels nexus phones one plus, samsung... All seem to fail me.

Comment: Do you use a screen protector? That should help in moisturise interacting with screen, especially if it's tempered glass with a high rating

Comment: Runbo X3 or similar

Comment: @alecxs do you really suggest that only "rugged gear" things work in rain? I find that hard to believe: in a lot of places there are more days with rain than dry days. So why wouldn't high end mobiles aim for those?

Comment: first cars in the world where electric. i still can barely see on german roads. that's also hard to believe. i think only good old gsm cell phone with physical buttons is recommended. [google](https://www.ecosia.org/search?q=pixel+planned+obsolescense) is one of the worst quality products